# Making a type constraint based on runtime value of (maxBound :: Int)

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families, type-level-computation

I'm very new to type-level computations and type families and so on, and I'm trying to make a `Constraint` that will keep a type-level `Nat` from exceeding `maxBound :: Int`.

In order to future-proof the code a bit, I'm hoping for a solution that works properly whether compiling normally **or** cross-compiling to a machine with a different word size. It should limit the `Nat` based on the ***target machine's*** value for `maxBound :: Int` at runtime (if there's a way to get that exact value at compile-time and go from there, that's fine).

---

I got some help learning how to make constraints with compiler error messages, and here's my not-very-good first attempt at solving this problem:

```hs
type family BigUpperLimit (n :: Nat) (c :: Constraint) :: Constraint where
  BigUpperLimit n c = If (CmpNat n (maxBound :: Int) == 'GT)
                         (TypeError (    Text "UInt "
                                    :<>: ShowType n
                                    :<>: Text " exceeds UInt "
                                    :<>: ShowType (maxBound :: Int)
                                    :<>: Text ", the maximum size allowed with this machine's word size."
                                    )
                         )
                         c
```

It complains that `maxBound` isn't a known type variable. If I put a `'` in front of `maxBound`, it complains "Illegal promoted term variable in a type: maxBound".

---

How can I accomplish my goal? I'm open both to ways of fixing the above method and to completely different methods.

Comment: You can't.  That would require the bounded api to expose the bounds as type-level information, but it doesn't.  You could make your own class that does and instantiate it all the types you are going to use.  Not sure how to do the target machine dependent stuff.

Comment: I really doubt that this target-machine dependency can work. I'm not that firm with GHC internals, but I think the machine-dependent stuff only start after finishing the type checking.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use CPP itself here.

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP                  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Type.Bool
import Data.Kind

#include "MachDeps.h"

type family BigUpperLimit (n :: Nat) :: Constraint where
  BigUpperLimit n = ( KnownNat n
                    , If (0 <=? n && n <=? WORD_SIZE_IN_BITS)
                         (() :: Constraint)
                         (TypeError (    Text "UInt "
                                    :<>: ShowType n
                                    :<>: Text " exceeds UInt "
                                    :<>: ShowType WORD_SIZE_IN_BITS
                                    :<>: Text ", the maximum size allowed with this machine's word size.")))
```

Now you can:

```
*Main> 2 :: BigUpperLimit 12 => Int
2
*Main> 2 :: BigUpperLimit 120 => Int

<interactive>:34:1: error:
    • UInt 120 exceeds UInt 64, the maximum size allowed with this machine's word size.
    • In the expression: 2 :: BigUpperLimit 120 => Int
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = 2 :: BigUpperLimit 120 => Int
```

Note that the latter is a type-error:

```
*Main> :t 2 :: BigUpperLimit 120 => Int

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    UInt 120 exceeds UInt 64, the maximum size allowed with this machine's word size.
```